# How to Read Numeric Data From Text file and save it to a variable using python

Tags: python, text, numeric

I am working on a project that gets data from a text file and that value needs to be stored in  a variable. but the following code does not work properly. sometimes it works while other times it returns

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

the following is the code used:

```
def main():
    # Txt read
    global id
    input = open('data.txt', 'r')
    lines = input.readlines()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i += 1
        id = int(line)

main()
print id
```

Data would be in single int followed by new line in text file.

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some of your files probably have an empty line at the end or elsewhere.

Comment: How to Rectify the error?

Comment: I think you can try with `try:....except: pass`, also in your code you are only assigning the value to id is the last element of your file, is that you want ?

Comment: yes @VikasDamodar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things first

Don't use `input` as a variable, since it's a built-in function in python. It is not considered a good practice.

Also, `id` also happens to be a built-in function, so avoid that as well

Also, I would suggest to read the whole file as string and the split based on `\n`. This will help you to strip the extra newlines at end (and start if you wish)

You can use something like this:

```
def main():
# Txt read

    input1 = open('text.txt', 'r').read().strip()
    l = input1.split("\n")
    #convert to int
    ll = [int(s) for s in l]
    print(ll)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you will get only last value in file for getting all values use list and store them in list and there is no need of `i` and increment of `i` if want to calculate total number of values use `len(id)`
Try Below code

```
def main():
  # Txt read
  global id
  id=[]
  input = open('data.txt', 'r')
  lines = input.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    if line.strip(): #Checking Non-Empty Line
      id.append(int(line.strip()))
main()
print id
print "Total Valuse: "+str(len(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline character "\n" is casing the error.

```
def main():
    # Txt read
    global id
    data = open('data.txt', 'r').read()
    data = data+'0'
    data = data.replace('\n','+0+')
    id = eval(data)


main()
print(id)
```